# Free vehicular traffic simulator

Tags: gratis, simulation

I'm looking for a free vehicular traffic simulator.  Basically, I need something that has a basic infrastructure for modeling the flow of traffic (preferably both highway and city traffic), while also allowing the user to program behaviours into the vehicles, or "agents" that modify how they travel.

Ideally, the agents would be able to navigate a given traffic system as a default, without the user doing anything, and then the user would be able to modify this behaviour.

I would prefer a graphical simulator that allows me to observe how the vehicles move in real time, rather than a purely number-based one.

I have access to both Windows 10 64-bit and Ubuntu 16.04 **32-bit**.

Comment: Are you looking for a graphic simulator or a numeric one?

Comment: Preferably a graphic one that allows me to observe how the vehicles move in real time.  I'll edit my post to include that.